# LinkId Not found but returned by calculateroute.json

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to avoid a linkId with here calculateroute.json (7.2), mode pedestrian, but i receive an ApplicationError => subtype => "LinkIdNotFound"
The problem is, when i verify if the linkId exists (call same endpoint calculateroute.json with same params exceipt avoidLinks and who start and destination are two point coordinates on my linkId), here returns the same LinkId in response.

In clear, linkId exists in route response when call coordinates everywhere on the linkid without avoid, but not exists if i try to avoid this link on any route.

What i'm wrong ?
LinkId is -4294967295, but i have others with same problem

- Call of a route with coordinates inside the linkid

[https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id={your_id}&app_code={your_code}&resolution=300&representation=navigation&linkAttributes=shape&mode=fastest;pedestrian;traffic:disabled&waypoint0=geo!43.607570,1.427560&waypoint1=geo!43.607570,1.427560&walkSpeed=1.2&language=fr](https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=%7Byour_id%7D&app_code=%7Byour_code%7D&resolution=300&representation=navigation&linkAttributes=shape&mode=fastest;pedestrian;traffic:disabled&waypoint0=geo!43.607570,1.427560&waypoint1=geo!43.607570,1.427560&walkSpeed=1.2&language=fr)

- Call of a route at proximity of the linkid with avoid this link produce the error linkidnotfound

[https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id={your_id}&app_code={your_code}&resolution=300&representation=navigation&linkAttributes=shape&mode=fastest;pedestrian;traffic:disabled&waypoint0=geo!48.83842,2.39298&waypoint1=geo!48.85180,2.35666&walkSpeed=0.97&language=fr&avoidlinks=-4294967295](https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=%7Byour_id%7D&app_code=%7Byour_code%7D&resolution=300&representation=navigation&linkAttributes=shape&mode=fastest;pedestrian;traffic:disabled&waypoint0=geo!48.83842,2.39298&waypoint1=geo!48.85180,2.35666&walkSpeed=0.97&language=fr&avoidlinks=-4294967295)

Answer (score 0):

The route shape for the waypoints in 2nd API doesn't include the link ID that you are trying to avoid. you can find all linkID that forms this path first and check if the removal linkID is actually present or not. hence it is throwing the error.